# Is there some way to easily map the source to its reference translation for the Google MQM Dataset?

Tags: python, pandas, nlp, dataset, machine-translation

## TL;DR

There is a dataset from https://github.com/google/wmt-mqm-human-evaluation that contains the source text and various machine translations, but its reference/human translations are missing.

The reference translations can be located on:

- https://data.statmt.org/wmt20/translation-task/test.tgz
- https://data.statmt.org/wmt21/translation-task/test.tgz
- [https://www.cs.jhu.edu/~kevinduh/a/multitarget-tedtalks/](https://www.cs.jhu.edu/%7Ekevinduh/a/multitarget-tedtalks/)

**Q: What is the simplest way to map the data from `wmt-mqm-human-evaluation` to their reference translations?**

---

## In Long:

There is this dataset that exists in multiple `.tsv` files on https://github.com/google/wmt-mqm-human-evaluation and the purpose of this data is that contains annotated translation errors from the **following test sets** created by previous machine translation shared tasks:

- **newstest 2020**: This is the dataset from Conference for Machine Translation (aka WMT) in year 2020 that are structured in this SGML format (basically an XML format for very specific use-cases, there's more explanation here in the 1997 paper but it's not that important)

  - Direct URL: https://data.statmt.org/wmt20/translation-task/test.tgz
  - Site explaning what the data contains and the shared task: https://www.statmt.org/wmt21/
- **newstest 2021**: Similar to the 2020 variant of the data set, this is for the 2021 shared task but structured in a more formal XML format (though without any DTD definition file).

  - Direct URL: https://data.statmt.org/wmt21/translation-task/test.tgz
  - Site explaning what the data contains and the shared task: https://www.statmt.org/wmt21/
- **TED talks**: This is a dataset created for the spoken machine translation shared task that originated from https://wit3.fbk.eu/ but the cleanest and most structured form is generated on [https://www.cs.jhu.edu/~kevinduh/a/multitarget-tedtalks/](https://www.cs.jhu.edu/%7Ekevinduh/a/multitarget-tedtalks/)

**Q (part 1):** How to map the annotations from `wmt-mqm-human-evaluation` to their reference translations?

---

### I've tried

To get the source to reference mapping from `newstest2020` and `newstest2021` I've parsed the XML as such:

**Downloading the data:**

```
! wget https://data.statmt.org/wmt21/translation-task/test.tgz 
! tar zxvf test.tgz
```

**Parsing the data:**

```
from itertools import chain
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with open('test/newstest2021.en-de.xml') as fin:
    bsoup = BeautifulSoup(fin)
    
en2de = {}
for doc in bsoup.find_all('doc'):
    if doc.find('ref'):
        en2de.update(
            dict(
                zip(
                    [seg.text for seg in doc.find('src').find_all('seg')],
                    [seg.text for seg in doc.find('ref').find_all('seg')])
            )
        )
        
with open('sgm/newstest2020-ende-src.en.sgm') as fin:
    en = [seg.text for seg in BeautifulSoup(fin).find_all('seg')]
with open('sgm/newstest2020-ende-ref.de.sgm') as fin:
    de = [seg.text for seg in BeautifulSoup(fin).find_all('seg')]
    
en2de.update(dict(zip(en,de)))
```

Then to download and parse the `tedtalk` dataset, I did something like:

```
! wget https://www.cs.jhu.edu/~kevinduh/a/multitarget-tedtalks/multitarget-ted.tgz 
! tar zxvf multitarget-ted.tgz
```

and then:

```
en_files, de_files = {}, {}
for filename in find_files('multitarget-ted/', '*en-de*'):
    prefix = filename.rpartition('.')[0]
    if filename.endswith('en'):
        en_files[prefix] = filename
    if filename.endswith('de'):
        de_files[prefix] = filename

en2de_ted = {}
for k in en_files:
    with open(en_files[k]) as en_fin, open(de_files[k]) as de_fin:
        en2de_ted.update({en.strip(): de.strip() for en, de in zip(en_fin, de_fin)})
        
en2de.update(en2de_ted)
```

Finally to join them up, I've tried reading the `mqm-dataset`:

```
from lazyme import find_files
import pandas as pd

lol = []

for filename in find_files('wmt-mqm-human-evaluation-main', '*.tsv'):
    if "avg_seg_scores" in filename:
        continue
    print(filename)
    df = pd.read_csv(filename, sep='\t', error_bad_lines=False)
    #print(len(df))
    df = df[~df['source'].str.contains('|'.join(['\t']),  na=False)]
    #print(len(df))
    
    ann, dataset, lang = filename.split('_') 
    
    df['filename'] = filename.split('/')[-1]
    df['src_lang'] = lang[:2]
    df['trg_lang'] = lang[2:4]
    df['annotation_scheme'] = ann
    
    if len(lang.split('.')) > 2:
        df['special_category'] = lang.split('.')[1]
    else:
        df['special_category'] = "general"
        
    lol.append(df)

df_google_mqm = pd.concat(lol)
```

Then mapping it to `zh2en` and `en2de` dictionaries:

```
targets = []
num_none = 0
for src in df_google_mqm['source']:
    if src in zh2en:
        targets.append(zh2en[src])
    elif src in en2de:
        targets.append(en2de[src])
    else:
        num_none += 1
        targets.append(None)

df_google_mqm['reference'] = targets

df_google_mqm = df_google_mqm[df_google_mqm['reference'].notna()]
```

With the above code, I'm still missing around 88,471 data points out of the full 555,990 from the `wmt-mqm-human-evaluation` dataset.

A working code for the above can be found on https://www.kaggle.com/code/alvations/lightyear2

**Q (part 2):** Have I missed something when trying to map the data with the above attempt?

**Q (part 3):** Is there a simpler way to map the data to their reference/human translations?

Comment: Have you asked the authors of the `wmt-mqm-human-evaluation` to just publish the data with their references?